# UI in Interface Builder doesn't match UI on a device

Tags: ios

I am totally new to iOS development. Just starting working in Xcode 4. I build UI using IB, but when running it on simulator or an actual device UI is rendered differently (I get overlapping buttons on the device or simulator, although everything is displayed correctly in IB). None of the controls were created with code. Everything was done in IB. I copied some buttons in IB as they are performing the same logic and hooked up to the same IBAction. I checked view hierarchy - everything looks right.

Any idea what might be causing it?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Take a look to the option of your xib's simulated metrics.Check attached screen shot.[image]

Comment: I am using storyboards. I can't find simulated metrics option in inspector.